# How to differentiate code running in production and staging slots

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have 2 Azure Functions: Azure Function 1 and Azure Function 2.

Azure Function 1 is timer trigger function which runs every n minutes and puts a message to a queue.

Azure Function 2 is a service bus trigger function which gets triggered after receiving a message from the queue

As of now, I only have one deployment slot for these 2 functions - production slot.

I'm trying to add a new staging slot for both functions.

Both staging slot and production slot will have same app settings (uses same queue, same log workspace).

Now, let's say Azure Function 1 gets triggered and puts a message to queue. Will there be 2 messages in the queue (from Azure Function 1 in staging slot and production slot)? Will Azure Function 2 in both staging slot and production slot gets triggered after receiving the message? Please help me understand.

UPDATE:

For clarification, my understanding is that both production and staging slots are in running state all the time. So, Azure Function 1 (timer trigger function) in both staging and production slots get triggered and put a message to the same queue (since both slots use the same queue). Will there be 2 messages in the queue? If so, will Azure Function 2 in both production and staging slots get triggered (since Azure Function 2 is a service bus trigger function)? So, should different queues be used for production/staging slots?

Comment: did u find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like you will need to either use a different queue in the code for your slot.
I am working with a customer who had a similar issue with their main Function and slot both triggering. There is info here recommending to disable the slot if you don't want it triggering.

> By default, app settings also apply to apps running in deployment
> slots. You can, however, override the app setting used by the slot by
> setting a slot-specific app setting. For example, you might want a
> function to be active in production but not during deployment testing,
> such as a timer triggered function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal#functions-in-a-slot

Altering the code of the slot to refer to a test queue should work as well, but then you would need to change it back before swapping if you plan to swap.
I don't know how the queue trigger specifically behaves but I would assume that 2 messages will be passed to the queue (1 from main Function and 1 from slot).

This thread also describes an issue where main Function and slot triggered off Service Bus.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49834